# What are the differences between "during" and "in"?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, conjunctions

What are the differences between "during" and "in"?

Recently, I send an e-mail to complain about game(haha). I wrote

> I understand the point that this game is **during** construction

or should I write

> I understand the point that this game is **in/under** construction.

Comment: "during" is not correct here. You could also use, more accurately, **in development**, rather than under construction because it's a software.

Answer (score 1):

During is generally used to give context to something else. e.g. "There were problems during construction."

You would never say 'in construction' unless you were talking about someone's job. e.g. "He works in construction" => his job is building things.

Construction is not used in reference to software, but generally only to buildings. In this case you would say 'in development'.